# How to embed multiple audio files to one video file with timeline offset?

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, sox

I have a video file:

```
screencast.mpg (100sec)
```

And several audio files(file name indicate offset):

```
10.wav (10sec)
30.wav (5sec)
45.wav (8sec)
```

How can I combine those files together:

```
V:||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
A:    .....     ...     ....
```

I want to write a script to do this job automatically.
I've tried `ffmpeg -itsoffset` option, but failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code assumes that your `.wav` files are `4800 Hz` and `stereo`.
It builds segments of silence, based on the above values.
It produces a single `.wav`.  which can be muxed with the video.

```
nrChannels=2
sampleRate=48000

rawSilence() {
  local nrSeconds=$1
  local sampleRate=$2
  local nrChannels=${3:-2}
  ffmpeg -acodec pcm_s16le \
         -ar $sampleRate \
         -ac $nrChannels \
         -f s16le \
         -i <(dd if=/dev/zero bs=$((sampleRate*2*nrChannels)) count=$nrSeconds) \
         -f s16le -
}

{ 
  rawSilence 10 $sampleRate $nrChannels 
  cat "10.wav" |ffmpeg -f wav -i - -f s16le -
  rawSilence 10 $sampleRate $nrChannels
  cat "30.wav" |ffmpeg -f wav -i - -f s16le -
  rawSilence 10 $sampleRate $nrChannels
  cat "45.wav" |ffmpeg -f wav -i - -f s16le -
  rawSilence 47 $sampleRate $nrChannels
} |
  ffmpeg -acodec pcm_s16le \
         -ar $sampleRate \
         -ac $nrChannels \
         -f s16le \
         -i - \
         -f wav -y 100sec.wav
```

To mux the video and audio together, this or some encoding variant should do it:

```
ffmpeg -i "100sec.mpg" \
       -i "100sec.wav" \
          -vcodec copy \
 -y "100sec.muxed.mpg"
```